# Do I have to do service to a get shell from localhost?

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I want to use ssh from localhost to Pod. Is there any way to connect using `ssh [Pod_IP]` without using `kubectl exec -it [Pod] /bin/bash`?

The results are as shown in `ERROR: ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: Connection refused`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this goal by installing `openssh-server` on the targeted Pod

**For example:**

Establish SSH connection to the Pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <Pod_name> -- /bin/bash
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

Ensure that SSHD service is up and running:

```
$ service ssh status
```

Start it if necessary:

```
$ service ssh start
```

Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file if you want to change some specific settings, and restart the SSH service.

Check the connection via SSH from your local machine using Pod IP address.

**Update:**

I use the following Pod configuration in order to establish SSH connection to the Centos 7 container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: centos
spec:
  containers:
  - name: centos
    image: centos:latest
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "yum install openssh-server -y && /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A && /usr/sbin/sshd -p 
22 -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config && tail -f /dev/null" ]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```